# Why does my while loop end after one round through?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

```
def transpose(matrix):
    n=0
    while n < (len(matrix)):
        li = []
        for sets in matrix:
            li.append(sets[0])
        n += 1
        print(len(matrix))
        return li
transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Currently returns [1,4,7]
Wanted result [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]

Comment: `return` ends function - you have to use `return` after `while` loop.

Comment: Because that's how you coded it - you run through the instructions in the loop, and the last statement is `return`.

Comment: The result I am receiving is just [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `return` statement within your while, so the function returns once it reaches that point. You should *dedent* your return to the same level as the while:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    n = 0
    li = []
    while n < (len(matrix)):
        ...
    return li
```

You could also replace the while loop and counter `n` with a for loop that iterates on `range(len(matrix))` so you can safely discard `n`, and then move the initialization of `li` outside the loop:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    li = []
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        inner_li = []
        for sets in matrix:
            inner_li.append(sets[i])
        li.append(inner_li)
    return li
```

I suggest you adopt the popular recipe for transposing matrices to make your code cleaner:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return list(zip(*matrix))
```

---

```
>>> transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: The result I am receiving is just [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9].

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fix for your original code

Comment: Thank you for your help managed to make it work with my while loop as well. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters. Additonally  the list `li` was being initialized at the wrong location.

```
def transpose(matrix):
    n=0
    li = []

    while n < (len(matrix)):
        for sets in matrix:
            li.append(sets[0])
        n += 1
        print(len(matrix))
    return li
```

Comment: The result I am receiving is just [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9].

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you know this, but just in case, this can be accomplished with numpy

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print A.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is the indented `return`.
The second is having `0` instead of `n` within `sets[...]`.
The third is overwriting the value of li in every while-loop.
This is how it works:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    n=0
    li = []
    while n < (len(matrix)):
        li.append([])
        for sets in matrix:
            li[-1].append(sets[n])
        n += 1
        print li
    return li


transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Don't worry about it. You will become faster and less error-prone very quickly if you are curious and try things out :)